# how do i ask something on this website about array's

Tags: arrays

//:(this is the assigment)Updating the number of items
In the addToCart function, update the element with ID itemCounter to the length of the cartItems array.

var cartItems = [];

var backpack = {
 name: "Backpack",
 price: 400
}

var camera = {
 name: "Camera",
 price: 300
}

function addToCart(item) {
  cartItems.push(item);

}

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need this

```
var cartItems = [];

var backpack = { 
name: "Backpack", 
price: 400 
}

var camera = { 
name: "Camera", 
price: 300 
}

function addToCart(item) { 
cartItems.push(item);
document.getElementById("itemCounter").innerHTML = cartItems.length; 
}
```

It is pretty simle question if you know basics of JS.

Comment: Btw I guess you are just starting, please do use Indentation and Comments always even at the beginning, no matter how big or small code is, it will make your life easier in future when code goes up to 4, 5k lines.